# Laravel API Route Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to test an API route, but I always get `404 Not Found`.

I'm using this command:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/api/veip
```

This is my `routes/api.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/veip', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

And this is my `php artisan route:list` output:

```
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/veip |      | Closure | api        |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
```

So the route does exists

I don't know what's going on here...

Comment: typo in curl command `ipve`

Comment: Hussein, thanks for commenting, it was a typo in the question. The problem is still happening

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` if you changed the route then try again

Comment: Can you confirm that `.htaccess` is enabled and is working?

Comment: Does your project root folder have the right permission? Try  `sudo chmod 755 -R project_root_folder`

Comment: If you have changes `RouteServiceProvider.php` `mapApiRoutes()` you should open the website via `api.websitename.test/veip` but if this file has not been touched you can run the website `websitename.test/api/veip`

Answer (score 4):

try php artisan route:clear may work for you

Answer (score 4):

Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable the mod_rewrite on the .htaccess file, then `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 2):

check routing middleware https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups?

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {

    Route::get('testroute', [TestController::class, 'index']); 
}
```

URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/testroute
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call http ://my_localhost_link/**api**/someroute.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem earlier, turn out i just had to run `php artisan optimize` and my routes were there

Comment: for me `php artisan optimize:clear` going well

Answer (score -3):

You need to search Api/routes using: php artisan api:routes (artisan command) instead of php artisan route:list.

Comment: Can you explain that further? How do these commands solve the 404 error?

Comment: I got the same error code while trying to get the route:list but i realised i was typing another command for getting to Routes. That spent me a lot of time. And i did not have any error.

Comment: Please explain that further, and add all explanation to the answer, not to the comment section. Keep in mind that the OP should be able to solve the problem using your answer

Comment: I get `There are no commands defined in the "api" namespace.`